# Change css float properity on click with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do a dark mode button for my website. my idea is to use an event on click to change the side of my button switch from left to the right and right to the left. it works on my first click, it switches from left to the right (from off to on). But when I try to switch it back again nothing happens. Here's my code

```
const buttonmode = document.querySelector("#darkmode");
const switchmode = document.querySelector("#darkswitch");

buttonmode.addEventListener("click",(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    if(switchmode.style.float="left"){

        switchmode.style.float="right";
    } 
    else if(switchmode.style.float="right"){
        
        switchmode.style.float="left";
    }
});
```

```
heres my css
button span{
    display: block;
    background: #999;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 2px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Please may you add the HTML as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you define `switchmode` variable outside of the function and re-use it in your function. Whenever DOM gets updated, your variable is not updated as you expected. You should get `switchmode` again for the next updates in the function.

You also have a small problem here

```
if(switchmode.style.float="left")
```

It should be `===` instead of `=` for if-else condition.

```
const buttonmode = document.querySelector("#darkmode");

buttonmode.addEventListener("click",(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const switchmode = document.querySelector("#darkswitch"); //move it here
    if(switchmode.style.float==="left"){

        switchmode.style.float="right";
    } 
    else if(switchmode.style.float==="right"){
        
        switchmode.style.float="left";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using classList.toggle

```js
const themeSwitcher = document.getElementById("themeSwitcher");

themeSwitcher.addEventListener("click", function () {
  this.classList.toggle("dark");
});
```

```css
#themeSwitcher {
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #252525;
}

#toggler {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dark #toggler {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="themeSwitcher">
  <div id="toggler"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your conditional statement, in order to check what the current `float` value is you need to use `==` not just `=`

```js
const buttonmode = document.querySelector("#darkmode");
const switchmode = document.querySelector("#darkswitch");

buttonmode.addEventListener("click",(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    if(switchmode.style.float == "left") {
        switchmode.style.float="right";
    } else {
        switchmode.style.float="left";
    }
});
```

```css
#darkswitch {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<button id="darkmode">Dark Mode</button>
<div id="darkswitch"></div>
```